# How can I implement Circular SSTF in this code?

Tags: python, algorithm, operating-system

In my Operating Systems class, we have to present one algorithm as our final project. A mock model for any of the OS algorithms. I choose an algorithm which is an improved/variation of regular SSTF algorithm. It is called Circular SSTF. I have already implemented SSTF in python. But I can't figure out a way to implement Circular SSTF. Any help or tips on that will be much appreciated.

Here's an explanation of both the algorithms.

Given
Suppose that the requests are : 98, 183, 37, 122, 14, 124, 65, 67.

- Assume that in the beginning, the disk head is at cylinder 53.
- Suppose that the device queue length is 20 requests.
- Assume that moving the head from one track to the next takes 1 ms.
- Ignore the service time.

Based on SSTF algorithm the OS will allocate the requests in the following manner,

> The order is : 53, 65, 67, 37, 14, 98, 122, 124, 183. Total head
>
> movement : 12+2+30+23+84+24+2+59 = 236 tracks.

In this algorithm, we first check which of the requests is closer to the current head (53 in this case). The closest is 65 and then 65 becomes the current head, the closest to that is 67 and then 67 becomes the current hear and thus the algorithm is continued.

Based on Circular SSTF algorithm the OS will allocate the request in the following manner,

> The order is : 53, 65, 67, 37, 14, 183, 124, 122, 98.
>
> Total head movement : 12+2+30+23+31+59+2+24 = 183 tracks.

In the Circular SSTF the algorithm will switch if the too many requests are closer to either of the end (0-199). Thus, instead of going to 98 from 14 the algorithm forces to serve 183 because it is closer to the other end.

Also, sorry for my bad english. Been a while since I'd to write something this elaborative and technical.

Edit 1.
Described the algorithms and removed the code as it could cause unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Do you want to fix an issue, or optimize your approach/program?

Comment: I want to implement the second algorithm Circular SSTF. I have already implemented SSTF and it's working fine. I'm sure it needs a few changes and I can modify it to process Circular SSTF output.

Comment: The description of "Circular SSTF" isn't a complete specification, because "too many requests are closer to either of the end" doesn't say what "too many" is, and what "closer to either of the end" means. Perhaps that's your difficulty?

Comment: @RISHABHTOMAR removing your code doesn't really help. The implementation difference between the two isn't significant, so it's easier to suggest a correction

Comment: @PaulHankin Umm yes. I wasn't able to describe the problem efficiently. What I actually wanted to say is that the next request is closer to the 0 or 199 instead of being closer to the current head. 

If we take the example from the above problem, after we have serviced 14 then according to SSTF, we'll serve 98 as it is the least difference from the remaining requests. 
But using Circular SSTF we will switch our sides and we will go to the right of the list and service 183. 

I hope I was clear. Apologize for the insufficient description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key difference between SSTF and Circular SSTF would be how the difference between head and sector is calculated. While it is simple modular difference for SSTF, in Circular SSTF it becomes:

```py
def difference(head, sector, end=199):
    diff1 = abs(head-sector) # going straight from head to sector
    diff2 = head + (end-sector) # going to 0 and then from end to sector
    diff3 = (end-head) + sector # going to end and then going from 0 to sector
    return min([diff1, diff2, diff3])
```

Ran your input against this, returned

```
The order will be: 
65  
67  
37  
14  
183  
124  
122  
98  

Output with SSTF algorithm: 
Head Movement: 182
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much friend. I tired multiple different ways to try and implement and I wasn't able to think of this. This makes complete sense. Thanks man. Really appreciated.